# Can column-count be split into 2 checkbox areas in a div?

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, column-count

I have a list of checkboxes in a div and some jquery which splits the enabled checkboxes and places them in an area above the disabled checkboxes (this is nothing to do with 'ticked' checkboxes).  For each area, I want to display 2 columns in a vertical flow so the checkboxes show alphabetically top down.  The layout of the labels should be as follows:

```
Austria        Germany
Denmark        Hungary
Estonia        Latvia
_______________________

Bulgaria       Ireland
Croatia        Malta
```

The country list needs to be flexible, so simply rearranging the labels in HTML won't work.  I've naively tried using column-count and column-width, but this messes up the enabled and disabled checkbox areas.  Ideally a CSS solution would be great but not sure its possible.  Any help greatly appreciated. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d7c56s00/

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

<div class="CountryListBoxClass_prodn">

  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN100" value="Bulgaria" />Bulgaria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN191" value="Croatia" />Croatia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN208" value="Denmark" />Denmark</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN233" value="Estonia" />Estonia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN276" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN348" value="Hungary" />Hungary</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN372" value="Ireland" />Ireland</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN428" value="Latvia" />Latvia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN470" value="Malta" />Malta</label>

</div>
```

.

```
$(function() {

  // Disable selected checkboxes
  $('.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label input[id="UN100"], input[id="UN191"], input[id="UN372"], input[id="UN470"]').prop('disabled', true);

  // -------------------

  // Group 'enabled' checkboxes above 'disabled'
$('input[type="checkbox"]') .filter(':enabled').parent().prependTo('.CountryListBoxClass_prodn').filter(':last').after('<hr />');

}); // End function
```

.

```
.CountryListBoxClass_prodn {
  //column-count: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 213px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate divs

```js
$(function() {

  // Disable selected checkboxes
  $('.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label input[id="UN100"], input[id="UN191"], input[id="UN372"], input[id="UN470"]').prop('disabled', true);

  // -------------------

  // Group 'enabled' checkboxes above 'disabled'

  $('input[type="checkbox"]') .filter(':enabled').parent().prependTo('.above').filter(':last');

}); // End function
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.above, .bellow{
  column-count: 2; column-width:50%;
  column-rule:none;   
  width:100%;
  padding:2em;
  border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 213px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CountryListBoxClass_prodn">
  <div class="above">
  
  </div>
  <div class="bellow">
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN100" value="Bulgaria" />Bulgaria</label>
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN191" value="Croatia" />Croatia</label>
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN208" value="Denmark" />Denmark</label>
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN233" value="Estonia" />Estonia</label>
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN276" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN348" value="Hungary" />Hungary</label>
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN372" value="Ireland" />Ireland</label>
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN428" value="Latvia" />Latvia</label>
    <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN470" value="Malta" />Malta</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's very cool. Hadn't realised column-count could be handled in this way.